# How to pass additional data to the callback when we pass Guid object as user state?

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, webservice-client

I want to parse a Property class to the `callback` method ,so I can specify what action should be performed when `callback` completed.

```
    // I have a webservice proxy created , in that webservice there is a method called Test which returns an integer value. 
       Myserver.servic service = new  Myserver.servic() ; 

        // In here i am calling Test webmethod asyncronously 
           public void test(ccc sk , int id )
            {
                service.TestCompleted -= testCompleted;
                service.TestCompleted += testCompleted;
               //When I am caling the TestAsyn method I am parsing Guid.NewGuid() 
               //Because I call the same method many times simultaneously.
               service.TestAsync(Guid.NewGuid ());
               //But this is not how i  want to call it 
               //I meant i want to parse some additional data to Callback method. 
               //In socket we can do it using AsyncState , but in WebService we cann't use UserState to parse custom data 
               //Because we have to parse a Guid object to it, otherwise it will generate the following error message 
               //Error: **There was an error during asynchronous processing. Unique state object is required for multiple asynchronous simultaneous.**   

               // Inorder to prevent getting this error, I have to parse new guid object as UserState 
               // But I also need to parse some data to Callback method  
               // Smething like this 
               //I.e 
               MyClass m = new MyClass () ;
               m.s = "Hello" ; 
               m.i = 292; 
               m.enable = true ; 
               service.TestAsyn(m) ; // I want to parse data this way
               // But if I parse data to call back method this way I will get that error again 
               // Can someone please help me ? 
          }
 // When Call back completed I want to use something like following
            public void TestCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());


                if (e.Error == null)
                {
                    MyClass  m = (MyClass )e.UserState;
                    MessageBox.Show(m.s);
                }

        } 
  }
```

Comment: Could anyone please help me? I am struck here... Please help me

Answer (score -1):

Create method overloading [Not Tested]

```
void by_server_AddFriendCompleted(int user,int friend, Guid NGuid, object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //I want soemthing like e.Parameter ? , like we use AsyncState in sockets
            // ex :  Myperopetyclass c = e.Parameter , this is what i want  

            if (e.Error != null)
               //error
        }
```

Comment: Are you serious ? ,  This is not answering my question , not at all  , Are you not familiar with Asyncronus procedure at all ?  , i do not want to parse Guid object to call back as a parameter , instead i want to parse another object as a parameter to call back , and the way you said me to pass parameters are really rediculous, It won't be possible to parse parameters that way .